# За что отвечает галочка Embed Interop Types в VS?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

На сборках Office есть такая галочку : Embed Interop Types

За что она отвечает? С этой галочкой нет возможности копировать локально сборку.

Я заметил, что если ее отключить, то некоторые операции с объектами офиса требуют явного приведения типа.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20515311/5796587 оно?

Comment: @rdorn, похоже на то.

Comment: интересная опция, надо будет попробовать на чем-нибудь насколько оно реально работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оригинал ответа на EnSO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515311/5796587

> Эта опция была введена для того, чтобы удалить необходимость развертывания очень больших interop-сборок (PIAs - > Primary Interop Assemblies).
>
> Включение этой опции позволяет встроить управляемый код для связи с неуправляемыми сборками в вашу сборку, но вместо того, чтобы встраивать весь код interop-сборки, встраивает только элементы, которые реально используются в вашем коде.
>
> Подробнее в блоге Скотта Хансельмана об этом и других улучшениях Visual Studio **[здесь](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CLRAndDLRAndBCLOhMyWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx)**. Дополнительная информация **[тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt632256.aspx)** и **[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515311/5796587)**.

Перевод достаточно вольный, для практического применения используйте оригинальные материалы по ссылкам в этом или оригинальном ответе.